# why is javascript array index set by array length

Tags: javascript

Came across this code, and it had me scratching my head, and wondered is their benefits to grabbing the length to set the index.

```
var thisarray = new Array();

    function addtoArray(int){
        thisarray[thisarray.length] = int;
    }
```

over array.push

```
 function addtoArray(int){
        thisarray.push(int)
    }
```

Also, is there an equivalent to this php

```
thisarray[]
```

Comment: Yes, `thisarray[thisarray.length] = something` is equivalent to PHP's `thisarray[] = something`. And `push()` is equivalent to `array_push()`.

Comment: This could be interesting: [Why is array.push sometimes faster than array\[n\] = value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614126/why-is-array-push-sometimes-faster-than-arrayn-value).

Comment: Javascript's push is *not* "equivalent" to PHP's array_push.  Javascript's push is an object/instance method; it is called directly on the array using dot notation.  With PHP's array_push, you must pass the array as an argument.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a reason JavaScript developers don't use Array.push()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649899/is-there-a-reason-javascript-developers-dont-use-array-push)

Comment: In my experience not using push is an indication that the developer has been using Javascript a very long time, since *before* push was introduced/fully-supported -- I can remember when it wasn't an option, back around 1998/99.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the example you have posted, the two uses are the same. Both append a new element to the end of the array.

However, the `push()` method can take multiple arguments and so you can append multiple elements to the end of the array in one statement. `push()` then returns the new length of the array. `push()` is also shorter and arguably easier to read.

Another thing to consider is that if `thisarray` has been incorrectly defined (ie. it is not an Array object) then `thisarray[thisarray.length] = int;` is likely to fail silently since `.length` will simply be `undefined`. Whereas `thisarray.push(int)` will fail with a trappable TypeError exception.

Regarding PHP's `thisarray[]` (square bracket) syntax. There is nothing quite the same in JavaScript, as far as syntax goes. However, `thisarray[thisarray.length] = int;` performs the same action.

Answer (score 2):

`thisarray[thisarraylength] = int` and `thisarray.push(int)` are identical. Arguably, the only advantage the latter has over the former is readability.

You might also find answers to this question useful: [Why is array.push sometimes faster than array[n] = value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/614126/7432)

Comment: To see how they are identical you can check out this snippet from the v8 source, https://gist.github.com/5958737. Also see: http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es5.html#sec-15.4.4.7