# Why are performing JavaScript functions slower than doing the same thing manually?

Tags: javascript, performance

An example of what I'm talking about.

This implementation, is much faster..

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var currIndex = 0;
var copied = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  copied[currIndex] = data[i];
  currIndex++;
}
```

Than this:

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var copied = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  copied.push(data[i]);
}
```

It's obvious that when writing JS, most people would write the second implementation as it's clearer what they're doing. Plus, with the first one, you are re-inventing the wheel.

Not sure why JS functions are so expensive.

Comment: `copied.push(data[i);` isn’t valid.

Comment: Define "much faster". "why JS functions are so expensive" --- *expensive* compared to *what*?

Comment: Related: [Why is `array.push` sometimes faster than `array[n] = value?`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/614126/4642212) and [Is there a reason JavaScript developers don’t use `Array.push()`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15649899/4642212).

Comment: @Xufox yes it is...

Comment: Inlining an operation is often faster than calling a function that does that operation.  `copied[currIndex] = data[i];` is inlining the operation rather than calling a function.  Same in lots of languages.  Plus, `.push()` may have some error checking on it that you do not.  You would expect `obj.i++` to be faster than `obj.increment(i)` right?

Comment: Is your question "why are functions slower", or "why do people use functions even though they're slower"?

Comment: Related:  [Javascript for..in vs for loop performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645890/javascript-for-in-vs-for-loop-performance) and: [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)