# generate object from a range get null on first iteration

Tags: javascript

What's wrong with my looping? The first iteration has null?

```
generateRewardOptions = () => {
        let options = []
        const max = 20

        for(let i = 1; i <= max; i++){
            options[i] = {
                key: i,
                value: i,
                text: i
            }
        }

        return options
    }

console.log(JSON.stringify(generateRewardOptions()));
```

https://jsbin.com/cupelanotu/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Alternative: `Array.from({length: 20}, (el, i) => ({key: i, value: i, text: i}));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option in addition to what smnbbrv suggestes is to use `push` in your loop:

```
for(let i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
    options.push({
        key: i,
        value: i,
        text: i
    });
}
```

and then you don't have to start at `i=0`.

Comment: this is easier but can have performance problems on big arrays, https://jsperf.com/array-direct-assignment-vs-push/5 (60% slower than direct assignment on modern chrome)

Comment: nice link. Thanks

Comment: @smnbbrv This test is flawed and does not reflect real array performance in Chrome, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034662/why-push-method-is-significantly-slower-than-putting-values-via-array-indices-in . According to https://jsperf.com/push-method-vs-setting-via-key/3 there is no significant performance difference between those two methods.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you start the loop from 1 when should start from 0.

Changing the for from 0 and excluding max should solve the issue:

```
for(let i = 0; i < max; i++){
```

JavaScript arrays are **0-based**

Comment: Good catch. Just make sure to use `i+1` inside the loop

Comment: but only when necessary, index should still remain `i`